# Stripping newlines from fread

Tags: c

I'm loading a file using this code, but it seems like removing the newlines also for some reason removes all lines but the first.

```
void load_script(char* path) {
    FILE* file;
    char* script;
    int filesize = 0;

    file = fopen(path, "r");

    // determine file size
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    // allocate memory
    script = malloc(filesize + 1);

    // read script
    size_t size = fread(script, 1, filesize, file);
    script[size] = 0;

    printf("Before stripping:\n%s\n", script);

    // strip newlines
    script[strcspn(script, "\n")] = 0;

    printf("After stripping:\n%s\n", script);

    fclose(file);
    tokenize(script);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Before stripping:
line 1
line 2
line 3
After stripping:
line 1
```

I'd love to know the best way to strip newlines from a multiline string. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
script[strcspn(script, "\n")] = 0;
```

This terminates the C-string after the first newline. You may want to loop over the string and replace  `\n'` with `' '` instead.

Something like:

```
// strip newlines
for(size_t i = 0; script[i]; i++)
if (script[i] == '\n') script[i] = ' ';
```

---

By the way, you should be using [`off_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/sys/types.h.html) (POSIX defined) to store the file size (as the type of `filesize`), not an `int`. An `int` may not be able to hold the size of a file.

Comment: Good explanation and fix, but your last remark on the type for the file size is not strictly correct: `ftell()` is defined as returning a `long`, not an `off_t` like `lseek`.  Type `long` may have a different size than `size_t`, converting it to `int` or `size_t` might truncate the value for very large files, and the very value may not even be the file size, so there is indeed a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution provided by l3x, I should add that the method used is not reliable:

- `ftell` may fail and upon success, its return value is the number of bytes in the file only if the file is opened in binary mode.  For text mode, the Standard does not guarantee anything beyond the fact that it can be used as an argument to `fseek`.
- seeking to the end of file and back to the beginning will not work as expected if the stream does not refer to an actual file: for a terminal, a character device or a pipe, it may not work at all.

It is much more reliable to read the file with `getc()` into a buffer that you reallocate on demand, one chunk at a time.